# Inlining SVG's not working on Unix Server but External SVG's ok

Tags: java, svg, apache-fop, batik

We are using Apache FOP to generate PDF's & have an issue with SVG's.

To include an SVG we're using something like the following...

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic  src="classpath:image/MyImage.svg"  content-width="150mm"/>
</fo:block>
```

The above works fine in all environments.

Now I'm trying to inline an SVG in the Stylesheet, like this...

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:instream-foreign-object content-width="272.6mm">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="780" height="120" viewBox="0 0 780 120">
            <g style="fill-opacity:0;stroke-width:2;stroke:black">
                <rect x="2"    y="2"   width="254"  height="99"/>
                <rect x="256"  y="2"   width="485"  height="99"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </fo:instream-foreign-object>
</fo:block>
```

That works OK under Windows, but when deployed on our Linux Server, seems to do nothing.

I have read some comments on the Apache FOP Website about it using Apache Batik to render SVG's and that this requires a Graphical Environment, so will not work in many Unix configurations.

What I don't understand is, how come the external SVG is working ok on the Unix Server & inline is not?

Also, they recommend a Tool called [PJA toolkit](https://www.eteks.com/pja/en/) to workaround this issue, but it looks very dated, so I wonder if its going to work with our JDK 17.

I would be grateful if anyone has some Info about this.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this example](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/dev/fo/embedding.fo.pdf)? There are different ways to include the namespace. I have no idea if it makes any difference.

Comment: That's the one I copied! I used the most usual Namespace convention from that example.  Works ok under Win (which is configured EXACTLY the same as our Linux deployment. Same JDK Version. Same Classpath Order) but generates nothing under Linux.  If that Namespace specification works there, it will work elsewhere.  Now take the SVG source from the instream-foreign-object & save it as a file & include it using external-graphic, then it works fine.  So why would FOP be able to use Batik to format the external-graphic correctly, but not be able to use Batik to format the instream-foreign-object?

Answer (score 0):

Previously we hadn't noticed the symptom, which was a spurious empty Namespace entry on the `<g>` Element, meaning it no longer belonged to the SVG Namespace:

```
<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="775" viewBox="0 0 1184 775" width="1184">
    <g xmlns=""  style="fill-opacity:0;stroke-width:7;stroke:red">
```

The problem turned out to be Namespace Awareness when parsing the Stylesheet.
When enabled, the generated inline SVG works fine.

Here's a Java Source to illustrate the Solution.
(it uses Multiline Strings which require JDK >= 14)
Just look for the TODO & (un)comment that line to see the difference:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class SvgNamespaceDomSimple {

    private static final String DATA_XML      = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dataXml/>""";

    private static final String STYLESHEET    = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"

            version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master  master-name="singlePage"  page-width="297mm"  page-height="210mm">
                    <fo:region-body  margin-left="2.19mm"  margin-top="6.75mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence  master-reference="singlePage">
                <fo:flow  flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:instream-foreign-object content-width="272.6mm" content-type="image/svg+xml">
                            <svg          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1184" height="775" viewBox="0 0 1184 775">
                                <g        style="fill-opacity:0;stroke-width:7;stroke:black">
                                    <rect width="254" height="99"/>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
""";

    private static Document parse(final byte[] byteArray) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        ;                            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);  // TODO setNamespaceAware(true)
        final DocumentBuilder        dbd = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        final Document               doc = dbd.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray));

        System.out.println("DocumentBuilderFactory.: " + dbf.getClass());
        System.out.println("DocumentBuilder........: " + dbd.getClass());
        System.out.println("Document...............: " + doc.getClass());

        return                       doc;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        System    .out.println("Data XML...............:" + '\n' + DATA_XML + '\n');
        System    .out.println("Stylesheet.............:" + '\n' + STYLESHEET);

        try(final ByteArrayInputStream  ist = new ByteArrayInputStream (DATA_XML.getBytes());
            final ByteArrayOutputStream ost = new ByteArrayOutputStream();)
        {
            final Document           stylesheetDoc      = parse(STYLESHEET.getBytes());
            final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

            final Templates          templates          = transformerFactory.newTemplates(new DOMSource(stylesheetDoc));
            final Transformer        transformer        = templates.newTransformer();

            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(ist), new StreamResult(ost));

            final String foString = new String(ost.toByteArray());

            System.out.println("TransformerFactory.....: " + transformerFactory.getClass());
            System.out.println("FO Bytes...............:"  + '\n' + foString);
            System.out.println(                                     foString.replace(">", ">" + '\n'));
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting inline SVG then looked something like this & was rendered fine both under Windows & on our Linux Server:

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object  content-width="272.6mm"  content-type="image/svg+xml">
    <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="1184"  height="775"  viewBox="0 0 1184 775">
        <g  style="fill-opacity:0;stroke-width:7;stroke:black">
            <rect  width="254"  height="99"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

As a workaround, you can specify the Namespace explicitly as follows:

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object  content-width="272.6mm"  content-type="image/svg+xml">
    <svg:svg  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="1184"  height="775"  viewBox="0 0 1184 775">
        <svg:g  style="fill-opacity:0;stroke-width:2;stroke:black">
            <svg:rect  width="254"  height="99"/>
        </svg:g>
    </svg:svg>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```